# Show extra admin menus to Shop Manager

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show my shop manager the Quick Redirect plugin menu in admin panel. Please let me know how this can be done. I have tried User Roles plugin, Adminize plugin but couldn't get it done.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Quick Redirect Menu]

Comment: This can not be done as the plugin need admin capabilities to get access to this plugin menu. So you should better ask in the Quick Redirect plugin support threads, if there is no a hook or some snippet code to allow woocommerce `shop_manager` user role.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I have posted the query on the plugin support forum.